# Attribute Searching

Tags: magento2, attributes, search

I'm trying to figure out how I can get **attributes** on the side of the category pages like this website has -

http://www.digitalsave.co.uk/phone-accessories/phone-tablet-protection/cases/

I've made an attribute and set it so it's searchable but not sure why I can't get it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the attribute filterable and the category needs to have the flag "Is Anchor" set to true.